# boot2docker: what does poweroff do to all my docker containers?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

When I use "boot2docker poweroff" and later "boot2docker up", what is the effect on my docker containers that are running at the time of the poweroff?  Is it like docker pause/docker unpause or docker stop/docker start?

And, when I reboot the host, I assume that boot2docker does a poweroff for me?  When the OS starts (Mac or Windows), does it do "boot2docker up" for me?

Experimentation shows

- "boot2docker poweroff" and "boot2docker up" is like "docker stop" without a "docker start"
- "boot2docker down" and "boot2docker up" is like "docker pause" and "docker unpause"

Is there any way to change the "up" behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I tested these scenarios and here is my finding:

Irrespective of how you stop boot2docker (i.e. `boot2docker stop/halt/down` or `boot2docker poweroff`), there is **no** action equivalent to `docker pause` and `docker unpause`.

The running containers gets stopped (`Exited (0)`) and if you haven't set restart policy in docker, they remain stopped.

[Here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker-cli/blob/8fdc6f573bf08149b6311681800d55fda6e19e71/main.go#L39) is the list of boot2docker commands and alias that may further help you.

boot2docker down/stop/halt sends `ACPI Shutdown` signal to VirtualBox where as boot2docker poweroff sends the `Power Off` signal to VirtualBox.

On the other hand, `boot2docker suspend/save` will save all the memory states and saves the container states as if we performed `docker pause/unpause`. i.e. if the containers were running before performing `boot2docker suspend/save`, then they will remain running after the command as well.

Hope this helped.